# ViewPager2 flashes/reloads on swipe

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager2

I'm trying to build an Android application using the new ViewPager2.  I've added two ViewPagers, separated by a view, and when you swipe, both viewpagers should move.  Both view pagers are moving correctly but upon completion of the gesture, the swiped view flashes and the non swiped view reloads, as demonstrated by the attached gif.  Here is my code for the Activity, ViewPagerAdapter, and Fragment.  Any help is appreciated

[image]

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding viewBinding;

    MyPager adapter1, adapter2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        viewBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        List<String> data = populateData();

        adapter1 = new MyPager(this, data);
        adapter2 = new MyPager(this, data);

        viewBinding.viewPager.setAdapter(adapter1);
        viewBinding.viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        viewBinding.viewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(data.size());
        viewBinding.viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(data.size());

        viewBinding.viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float positionOffset, final int positionOffsetPixels) {
                viewBinding.viewPager2.scrollTo(positionOffsetPixels, 0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) {
                viewBinding.viewPager2.setCurrentItem(viewBinding.viewPager.getCurrentItem(), true);
            }
        });
        viewBinding.viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float positionOffset, final int positionOffsetPixels) {
                viewBinding.viewPager.scrollTo(positionOffsetPixels, 0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) {
                viewBinding.viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewBinding.viewPager2.getCurrentItem(), true);
            }
        });

    }
    private List<String> populateData() {
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            String derril = "derril " + x;
            data.add(derril);
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

```
public class MyPager extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    List<String> data;

    public MyPager(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity, List<String> data) {
        super(fragmentActivity);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return DerrilFragment.newInstance(data.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
}
```

```
public class DerrilFragment extends Fragment {

    PizzaBinding viewBinding;

    String data;

    private DerrilFragment(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public static DerrilFragment newInstance(String data) {
        return new DerrilFragment(data);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        viewBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.pizza, container, false);

        viewBinding.text.setText(data);

        return viewBinding.getRoot();

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 ViewPagers? You only need 1.

Comment: because the viewpagers are separated by a view.  if you can do it in one viewpager, I'd be interested in hearing how

Comment: It looks like your ViewPagers are on top off each other. So it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: What about it doesn't make sense?  One ViewPager on top, separated by a view, then a second ViewPager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement by `RecyclerView`.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var isFirstFocused = false

    private val helper: SnapHelper = LinearSnapHelper()
    private val helper2: SnapHelper = LinearSnapHelper()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recycler1.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                if (isFirstFocused) recycler2.scrollBy(dx, dy)
            }
        })
        recycler2.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                if (!isFirstFocused) recycler1.scrollBy(dx, dy)
            }
        })
        recycler2.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
            if (event.action  != null && event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
                isFirstFocused = false
                return@setOnTouchListener  true
            }
            return@setOnTouchListener false
        }
        recycler1.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
            if (event.action  != null && event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
                isFirstFocused = true
                return@setOnTouchListener  true
            }
            return@setOnTouchListener false
        }
        helper.attachToRecyclerView(recycler1)
        helper2.attachToRecyclerView(recycler2)
        val manager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
        val manager2 = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
        recycler1.layoutManager = manager
        recycler2.layoutManager = manager2
        recycler2.adapter = Adapter(items)
        recycler1.adapter = Adapter(items)
    }

    private val items = listOf("One", "Two", "Three")

}

class Adapter(val list: List<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.Holder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.activity_listview,
            parent,
            false
        )
        return Holder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.text_view.text = list[position]
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = list.size

    class Holder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `adapter.setOffscreenPageLimit = n`. It sets the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the currently visible page(s). Pages beyond this limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed If you have a limited number of pages.
More details are [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)).

Answer (score 0):

In your `setCurrentItem()` usages (under `onPageScrollStateChanged()`), set the second parameter to `false`

This will disable animation (not permanently) in the ViewPager when you set a page programatically, which is the reason you see the flash-like animation.

---

To know why:

Consider two ViewPagers A & B

You scroll from one page to another in **A**, which induces the same scroll in `ViewPager` **B**. Once you completely scroll from one page to another in **A**, **the `currentItem` is internally set by A, but not for B**.

Now, you inform B about the page change by calling `setCurrentItem([index], true)`, which, irrespective of your scroll, will **animate** the page change introducing the flash (your induced scroll is reset to normal, and page animation for one page to another is started)

Answer (score 0):

this looks a bit suspicious that you are calling `setCurrentItem` inside `onPageScrollStateChanged` for every passed `state`... try to add some `if` and `setCurrentItem` only when `state==ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`

list of states:

- `ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`
- `ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING`
- `ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING`

`ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING` state is handled in `onPageScrolled` method (sharing position offset aka. dragging by finger)

`ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING` is auto-scroll (snap) of `ViewPager2` to closest page - in here I'm not shure that `ViewPager2` dragged "by code" (sharing position with `scrollTo`) will also enter in this `state` causing same snap behavior (so also `onPageScrolled`?) ... worth testing, put some logs in there

also: you are dragging one `ViewPager2` and in `onPageScrolled` you are calling `scrollTo` on second `ViewPager2`. this may lead to call `onPageScrolled` call on this second listener, which is calling first `ViewPager2` `scrollTo` method and so on... looped. consider dynamic unregistering listener when user will start drag one `ViewPager2` and reregistering when movement ends (`SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` `state`)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in '**onPageScrolled**' method of both ViewPagers you are scrolling other pager. So, both pages might be scrolling each other at the same. For example, if you are scrolling ViewPager_1 then its **onPageScrolled** method will scroll ViewPager_2 and as ViewPager_2 is now scrolled then its onPageScrolled method will be called and that will scroll ViewPager_1 and vice versa.
So, You may need to consider applying the check that if touch is holded ny ViewPager_1 then code inside **onPageScrolled** method of ViewPager_2 should not be executed. Or if you want to avoid those checks. Then **registerOnPageChangeCallback**/**unregisterOnPageChangeCallback** the listener of other ViewPager when one holds the touch.

```
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float positionOffset, final int positionOffsetPixels) {
                viewBinding.viewPager.scrollTo(positionOffsetPixels, 0);
            }
```

Comment: The problem is that the requirement for this feature is that it the swipes between each viewpager needs to be synchronized